# Google Kickstart 2020 Round E RuntimeError

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

Why am i Getting **RE** (Runtime Error) when testing my code in google ide ?

Here is the whole pastbin : **[Google Kick Start subject](https://pastebin.com/s2QJmT2U)**

here is a link to my Python Code with the inputs and output , which works fine : [Check_here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/vJiyzdGh45)

And for here is a copy past of my Code in case you don't want to bother checking an external link.

```
def Solution(cases_nbr):
    ans=[] # Output list
    
    for case in range(cases_nbr):
        dico={}
        input() # this is not needed
        # exmpl tmp_ls=10 7 4 6 8 10 11 will be -> 10 7 4 6 8 11 as int each
        tmp_ls=sorted(set(map(int,input().split()))) 
        for number in tmp_ls:
            # create a new key (number) on dico which holds empty list.
            dico[number]=[] 
            # loop through each uniq number in tmp_ls
            for cmp_n in tmp_ls:
                # check if the current cmp_n is not the current key (number)
                # and also check if its not alreay a key in dico
                if cmp_n!=number and cmp_n not in dico.keys():
                    # that will basically append the list : dico[key]
                    # with the Absolute diffrence between current number and cmp_n
                    dico[number].append(abs(number-cmp_n))
        
        # at the end of this loop we will have something like :
        # since the example i gave was 10 7 4 6 8 11 then the generated dico will be :
        
        #{4: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7], 6: [1, 2, 4, 5], 7: [1, 3, 4], 8: [2, 3], 10: [1], 11: []}
        #That way i will be able to find the longest contiguous arithmetic subarray
        # by simply checking the most found value in each list in dico
        
        tmp=[0,0]
        
        # i take the first list since it has the all the substraction results
        for diff in dico[list(dico.keys())[0]]:
            # then i loop through each value(diff) and check if it exists in the rest of the lists
            #tmp_count will end up having the count of diff in the other lists
            tmp_count=len([1 for k in dico.keys() if diff in dico[k]])
            # this if check if there is a longest count then it stores it in tmp[diff, count_val]
            if tmp[1]<tmp_count:tmp=[diff, tmp_count]
        
        # as we said
        # the resulted dico is :
        #{4: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7], 6: [1, 2, 4, 5], 7: [1, 3, 4], 8: [2, 3], 10: [1], 11: []}
        #basically the result should be len([4 6 8 10]) because thats the longest contiguous arithmetic subarray
        # However tmp now would have only : tmp[2,3] wheres it should have tmp[2,4]
        # that why i loop again through the keys and check if there is no tmp[0] which is 'diff' 
        # in that dico[key] list , for example : 10: [1]
        for _ in dico.keys():
            if tmp[0] not in dico[_]:
                # if so , i re-loop through [10 7 4 6 8 11] and test if  that 
                # abs(x-key) is equal to tmp[0] , in this case :
                # abs(10-6) is indeed == 2 , so i simply increment tmp[1] 
                tmp[1]+=len([_ for x in tmp_ls if x != _ and abs(x-_)==tmp[0] ])
        
        # that way i will end up having the correct result .
        
        # simply i append anser list with the formatted string output they said .
        ans.append(f'Case #{case+1}: {tmp[1]}')
    return ans

if __name__  == '__main__':
    cases_nbr=int(input())
    for ans in Solution(cases_nbr):
        print(ans)
```

Comment: I don't see an obvious place where an error would be likely to happen. Do you have a more detailed error message you could provide? Can you provide the description of the problem this code is trying to solve? Can you annotate your code with comments that describe what it's doing at each step, so it's easier for us to understand while we search for what the cause of the error might be?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Done (I'm bad at explaining code sometime ) , Please re-check it .